# Running Count of Non-Blank Cells in dynamic named range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use a single array formula to pull a running count of non-blank cells in a dynamic range. I know how to do it with a pasted formula with simple cell addresses like so:

=COUNTIF($B$3:B3,"<>")

However, this requires you to know how many cells you'll be filling and then paste the formula to as many cells. The ranges I'm dealing with will change based on input from the user. Please see below, with desired output in green, using pasted COUNTIF functions:

[image]

Dynamic ranges are displayed as text on Row 2. Their lengths are based on input to be pasted in Col D, and these ranges would be called via INDIRECT().

Can anyone provide a way that the Countif/Countifs logic from above can be translated to an Array Formula that uses dynamic ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Try below array formula-

```
=Arrayformula(COUNTIFS(B3:B, "<>", ROW(B3:B), "<="&ROW(B3:B)))
```

[image]